# C++ redefinition

Tags: c++, redefinition

I am trying to implement a function class, but got a error of redefinition. I know it is stupid, but can anyone please help?

=== header file ===

```
#ifndef _NS4_h
#define _NS4_h

#include <vector>
#include <list>

namespace NS4{
    class complex{
    double r, i;
    public:
        complex(double a=0, double b=0) : r(a), i(b) {};    
        complex operator+(complex c);
        complex &operator+=(complex c);
        complex &operator=(complex c);
    };

    // function class 
    class Add{      
        complex val;
    public:
        Add(complex c){ val = c; }
        Add(double r, double i) { val = complex(r, i); }
        void operator()(complex& c) const { c += val; } 
    };

    void h(std::vector<complex> &aa, std::list<complex> ll, complex z);
}
#endif
```

=== Part of the cpp file ===

```
using namespace NS4;
void test9()
{

    vector<complex> aa;
    aa.push_back(complex(0,1));
    aa.push_back(complex(0,2));
    aa.push_back(complex(0,3));

    list<complex> ll;
    ll.push_back(complex(1,1));
    ll.push_back(complex(1,2));
    ll.push_back(complex(1,3));

    complex zz(1,1);

    // the following line is not working
    // error C2371: 'zz' : redefinition; different basic types
    Add(zz);  // Add(complex(1,1)) is working.

    h(aa,ll, zz);
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use `void operator()(const complex & c) const` since you aren't modifying `c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an Add class, so you need to create an instance of it, in order to call the constructor.

So in the below case, `a` is an instance of our `Add` class.

```
Add a(zz);
```

Comment: isn't Add(zz) a constructor call where the result is discarded, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Kevin, no, constructors don't return anything, but in order to call the ctor, you need to create an instance of the Add class.  Not sure what you mean "where the result is discared"?

Comment: @Kevin: `Add(zz);` is an ambiguous statement, which can be interpreted as a declaration `Add zz;` or as an expression that creates a temporary of type `Add`. Such ambiguities in C++ are resolved in favor of the declaration.

Comment: @Kevin: Constructors don't have names. While you may think that you're creating an anonymous temporary that evaporates instantly, you're actually falling into a parsing trap. Try `(Add(zz));`.

Comment: @Tony The Lion: sorry too much java programming for me...I guess `new Add(zz)` would be creating an instance of Add and not assigning to anything...

Answer (score 2):

You can optionally put parenthesis around the variable name in a declaration.

```
int (i);
```

is the same as

```
int i;
```

So in your case you are declaring a variable named `zz` of type `Add`, and a variable named `zz` already exists. You probably meant to pass `zz` as an argument to `Add` constructor,  but then you should give some name to the variable:

```
Add adder(zz);
```

However, I don't see where that instance is used at all.

---

But if you just want to invoke the constructor of `Add` without declaring a variable, you can put parenthesis around the whole expression:

```
(Add(zz)); //just calls Add::Add(Complex);
```

Welcome to C++ ;)

Answer (score 1):

What is `Add(zz)` supposed to mean? What do you think it means?

`Add(zz)` is actually a declaration of object `zz` of type `Add`, i.e.

```
Add(zz);
```

is equivalent to

```
Add zz;
```

You have already defined `zz` before, which is why you get the redefinition error. No surprise here.

There's no way to help you further without knowing what you were trying to do by that `Add(zz)` line.